# Find for multiple tags' values with lxml

Tags: python, lxml, elementtree

I am using lxml to parse an XML like this sample one:

```
<compounddef xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" id="d2/db7/class_foo" kind="class">
    <compoundname>FooClass</compoundname>
    <sectiondef kind="public-type">
        <memberdef kind="typedef" id="d2/db7/class_bar">
            <type><ref refid="d3/d73/struct_foo" kindref="compound">StructFoo</ref></type>
            <definition>StructFooDefinition</definition>
        </memberdef>
    </sectiondef>
</compounddef>
```

I'm trying to get the element with `<refid>` "d3/d73/struct_foo" and with the `<definition>` containing the text "Foo".

There could be many refid with that value and many definitions containing Foo, but only one has this combination.

I am able to first find all the elements with that refid and then filter this list by checking which of them containts "Foo" in the , but since I'm working with a really big XML file (~1GB) and the application is time sensitive, I wanted to avoid this.

I tried combining the various etree paths using the keyword 'and' or '//precede:...', but without success.
My last try was:

```
self.dox_tree_root_.xpath(".//compounddef[@kind = 'class']//memberdef[@kind='typedef'][/type/ref[@refid='%s'] and contains(definition, 'name')]" % (independent_type_refid, name)))
```

but it is giving me an error.

Is there a way to combine the two filters inside one command?

Comment: Please show us your code. If you can use lxml instead of the built-in ElementTree module, more powerful XPath expressions are available.

Comment: @mzjn I updated the sample, and I corrected that I'm using lxml. Thanks.

Comment: You haven't shown us any runnable Python code (see [mcve]).

Comment: Unbalanced parentheses gives `SyntaxError: unmatched ')'`. Fixing that gives `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`. As @mzjn said, give an MRE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPATH

```
//a[.//ref[@refid="12345"] and contains(c, "Good")]
```

Comment: Thanks, unfornutaly I'm not able to make it run in my real case.
This is the actual line that I'm using:


self.dox_tree_root_.xpath(".//compounddef[@kind = 'class']//memberdef[@kind='typedef'][/type/ref[@refid='%s'] and contains(definition, 'name')]" % (independent_type_refid, name)))

But I am getting error in the path expression.

Comment: @Mdp11 , Update your source example with sample that looks like real HTML/XML

Comment: @Mdp11 try this `".//compounddef[@kind = 'class']//memberdef[@kind='typedef'][type/ref[@refid='%s'] and contains(definition, '%s')]" % (independent_type_refid, name)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your correctly, this should get you close enough:

```
.//compounddef[@kind = 'class']//memberdef[@kind='typedef'][./type/ref[@refid='d3/d73/struct_foo']][contains(.//definition, 'Foo')]//definition
```

Output:

```
StructFooDefinition
```